# Is it possible to find all association records to an object for consolidating records in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm wanting to add a function to a model of mine to consolidate two records.  If I have PlayerA and PlayerB for instance, and want to destroy PlayerB but assign all his current records to PlayerA.  I was going to make a method that would look up all his records and replace with PlayerA's id like so...

```
#...
Note.where(player_id: PlayerB.id).update_all(player_id: PlayerA.id)
HighScores.where(player_id: PlayerB.id).update_all(player_id: PlayerA.id)
Friends.where(player_id: PlayerB.id).update_all(player_id: PlayerA.id)
#...
```

Now if I do it this way I would have to remember to add one for each association that gets created in the future for the Player's Model.  Is there a way I could have this done dynamically, through perhaps some methods to pull all associations, so I wouldn't have to manually add for each new association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a right place for [ActiveRecord::Reflection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html).

```
Player.reflect_on_all_associations             # returns an array of all associations
Player.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many)  # returns an array of all has_many associations
```

So may be something like this could work for you:

```
associations = Player.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many)
associations.each do |association|
  associated_class = association.class_name.constantize # e.g. Note
  foreign_key      = association.foreign_key            # e.g. player_id
  associated_class.where(foreign_key => PlayerB.id).
                   update_all(foreign_key => PlayerA.id))
end
```

Note that this could be more tricky for complex associations like `has_and_belongs_to_many` though. For the sake of simplicity I do not cover that case here, but you could implement some conditional logics based on `association.class` which is a one of `ActiveRecord::Reflection` subclasses (`BelongsToReflection`, `HasAndBelongsToManyReflection`, `HasManyReflection`, `HasOneReflection`).

Comment: Thanks! I do have some HABTM associations to take care of but this is precisely what I was hoping to find.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a fast way for this, would love to hear if there is, but I did it the long way. I kept the old data around with an "imported" state so that it can be viewed when desired without getting in the way, and created a new version of each record, for each association type, with the new player's details.